# VBA learning Code, Look for word, consider the next column and if then

Tags: vba, if-statement, find, offset

I'm trying to learn VBA on my own so I'm doing to some basic stuff to mess around with it. What I'm trying to do right now is to look for the word "Total" inside of column A and after it finds the word consider the value on the next column then using the If then statement to judge if the number on column B is > then 1 then type on C1 "yes" or B1 "No"

```
Sub try5()

Set cell = Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:="Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Activate.Select

If cell > 1 Then
Range("C1").Value = "yes"

Else
Range("C1").Value = "no"

End If
End Sub
```

The first part of code, if I run it by it self works but VBA gives me a popup saying: "object required" while if I run with the IF THEN statement it says "Type mismatch".

Sorry if this is noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

1. Set the range you want to search for your value in
2. Set the `Found` cell in your search range as a range
3. Determine if a match is found before trying to analyze (Other wise `Found` = `Nothing` and the logical test `Nothing > 1` makes no sense.
4. Use `Offset(r, c)` to navigate `r` rows and `c` columns distance from the found cell (Here we want to look 1 column over so we use `Offset(0,1)` = `Offset(,1)`. Then, we want to look at Col C (2 columns away from A) so we use `Offset(,2)` to write `yes`/`no`

---

```
Sub try5()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim SearchRange As Range, Found As Range
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A:A")

Set Found = SearchRange.Find(What:="Total", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Found Is Nothing Then 'If a match is NOT found
    MsgBox "'Total' Not Found in Range " & SearchRange.Address(False, False)
Else 'If a match is found
    If Found.Offset(, 1) > 1 Then
        Found.Offset(, 2) = "yes"
    Else
        Found.Offset(, 2) = "no"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

---

I also do not recommend using `.Select`. You should always try to find a way to explicitly state what `Workbook`, `Sheet`, `Range`, or `Cell` you want to modify.  None of these objects have to be `Active` or `Selected` in order to be changed, deleted, moved, copied, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and explanation! The code is very detailed and it helped me understand. Is there any site or youtube you recommend so it helps me on the learning process?

Comment: I didn't know how to code VBA  like 6 months ago and learned via youtube channel (wiseowltutorials) and answering questions here. This site is essentially a non-stop supply of practice problems. The only reason I answer questions is for pratice. Give some questions a try. Study other peoples solutions to see what they did better and incorporate those methods in your next solution. Rinse and repeat